# Video in joomla

Tags: video, joomla

I have a joomla site, and I would like to have a video player that will play a video that has a link like the following

www.myjoomlasite.com/media/myvideofile.mp4

is there a way to do this? or do I have to use the a link link the following:

www.myjoomlasite.com/index.php?option=com_jvideo&view=watch&id=1&Itemid=7

I need the link to have the actually video file at the end in order for it to display in a video game I am developing. does anyone know how I can do this? What vidoe player I should use?

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use [AllVideos](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/812) plugin by [Joomlaworks](http://joomlaworks.gr).

It's simple and easy to use. The syntax is as follow :

{format/provider}filename|width|height|autoplay{/format/provider}

For example {youtube}he73js822|600|450|1{/youtube} to display videos from youtube.

Check the [documentation](http://www.joomlaworks.gr/content/view/35/41/). It shows how to embed a file on your directory

Comment: I installed the plugin, but i'm not finding the documentation on how to embed a file on my directory. Do you know where I can find that info? thanks in advance

Comment: Link to the documentation is added, check the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

There are better solutions, but maybe the easiest one is to upload a video file named myvideofile.mp4 to your /media folder.

Note that if you're using htaccess, Apache will allow you to access files matching a real file.

Another way might be creating a content category named "media", and an article with the necessary code inside it, but maybe you won't be able to add the mp4 extension to a menu item for an article (I'm not sure about that).

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend HTML5 player its easy to use just dump the files in the directory that your video is in.

Then
 link the video to the player in the html [JW Player/Html5 palyer](http://www.jwplayer.com/products/jwplayer/html5-and-flash/)

Or use a plugin such as
[SJ Simple HTML5 Video Player](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sj-simple-html5-video-player)  
its easy to use no codding involved and you can get the video to link/stream on other sites/apps.

Hope this helps. :)